# CouchDB document maximum size

Tags: database, couchdb

Just after some advice, as I'm brand new to CouchDB (and loving it so far). Just wondering if there are any limitations to the size of a single Document. Below is an example of a Document example.

```
{
    "_id": "client_info",
    "name": "Client Name",
    "role": "admin",
    ....
},
{
    "_id": "1199145600",
    "alert_1_value": 0.150
    "alert_2_value": 1.030
    "alert_3_value": 12.500
    ...
    ...
},
{
    "_id": "1199145900",
    "alert_1_value": 0.150
    "alert_2_value": 1.030
    "alert_3_value": 12.500
    ...
    ...
},
{
    "_id": "1199146200",
    "alert_1_value": 0.150
    "alert_2_value": 1.030
    "alert_3_value": 12.500
    ...
    ...
},
etc...literally millions more of these every 5 minutes...
```

<strike>The example above shows that I'll be storing data (timestamp and value) for several Data objects (eg, Data_1, Data_2, etc) under the object "values".</strike>

<strike>The trick here, is that each "values" object will need to store a significant amount of timestamp/value objects (around 2.5 million). I've added these through a script, just to test the limitations of the Document, but Futon crashes as it can't handle it.</strike>

<strike>I have a feeling i'm going about this the wrong way...</strike>

**UPDATE:** Revised code, now storing each data set in seperate documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you design CouchDB database, you must think in terms of documents. Here's an excerpt from http://guide.couchdb.org which I find very good:

> A rule of thumb: break up into documents everything that you will be handling separately in your application. Items are single, and comments are single, but you don’t need to break them into smaller pieces. Views are a convenient way to group your documents in meaningful ways.

Comment: Thanks @Gjorgji, i'm still trying to get my head around the new way of thinking! Instead of appending those timestamp/value objects to the above document, should each one be a seperate document (which is then shown with a view). I can't help but feel this to be a unorganised way of storing data, where everything is just placed in the root of the database...

Comment: View should be the way to organize your unorganized data :). Having in mind that you expect 2.5 million timestamp/value(s) for each Data_X, each of them should be a separate document. Make sure you read the CouchDB Guide. Havent't you considered using RDBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL)? I'm also relatively new to CouchDB and I feel that it is more appropriate when different "data chunks" are not so similar. In your case, the data is all the same.

Comment: Having only used MySQL, I wasn't sure if it would be able to retrieve values quick enough for that large of a data set. I've updated the original post with my revised technique. We'll see how it handles that after a few tests..